# A plant include Muti-body plant and LeafSystem plant

Tags: drake

A part of a plant is easily modeled by MutibodyPlant Class, unfortunately, other parts of a plant look like to be modeled by leaf System. Can Drake do such things?

- Plant A: muti-links arm --> Using SDF and MutibodyPlant class for modeling
- Plant B: an inertial wheel is attached to the end of the arm --> Using Leaf system to define dynamic(time derivate) of an inertial wheel.

[image: An illustration for this question]

Answer (score 0):

Wc. I'm not getting why you can't do the whole model in MultibodyPlant. The inertial wheel could be a link attached via a revolute joint. The controller that keeps it spinning at a desired rate would be a separate LeafSystem (like other controllers) that would use the revolute joint's rate as input and generate an actuator output (back to MBPlant).

Regards,
Sherm

Comment: Thank you for reply. I will try to do in that way you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Sherm.  But if you do have some non-rigid-body forces to apply, then you can certainly do what you’ve asked.  You just need to apply the “interaction forces” either through the actuation inputs or add a new spatial force input.